# Rust Yew.rs dropdown component

Tags: rust, yew

I have some code for dropdown link.

It works fine, but I'd like this code to work as usual. When we click somewhere outside or click the link inside, dropdown should be closed. How to implement this thing? If I don't want use Bootstrap js but only css.

```
use yew::prelude::*;

#[function_component(App)]
pub fn app() -> Html {
    let is_open = use_state(|| false);

    let onclick = {
        let is_open = is_open.clone();
        Callback::from(move |_| is_open.set(!*is_open))
    };

    html! {
        <main>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <a
                    class={classes!("btn", "btn-secondary", "dropdown-toggle")}
                    href="#" role="button"
                    data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                    aria-expanded="false"
                    {onclick}
                >
                 {"Dropdown link"}
                </a>

                <ul class={classes!("dropdown-menu", (*is_open).clone().then(|| Some("show")))}>
                 <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{"Action"}</a></li>
                 <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{"Another action"}</a></li>
                 <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{"Something else here"}</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </main>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do two things:

1. Attach the event handler to "the whole page", i.e. `body` to close your dropdown when clicked
2. Stop propagation of the `click` event from your dropdown to this event handler on `body`. Otherwise, the event will [bubble up](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_bubbling) to `body` as well, and you will get an open+close, effectively not allowing you to open the dropdown.

Add the following dependencies for ease:

```ini
gloo = "0.10.0"
wasm-bindgen = "0.2.87"
```

And change your component as follows:

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;

use gloo::utils::document;
use wasm_bindgen::{closure::Closure, JsCast};
use yew::prelude::*;

#[function_component(App)]
pub fn app() -> Html {
    let is_open = use_state(|| false);

    let onclick = {
        let is_open = is_open.clone();
        Callback::from(move |e: MouseEvent| {
            e.stop_propagation();
            is_open.set(!*is_open)
        })
    };

    {
        let is_open = is_open.clone();
        // Make a callback function that closes the dropdown
        let close = Rc::new(Closure::<dyn Fn()>::new({
            move || {
                is_open.set(false);
            }
        }));

        // When the component is mounted, attach the event listener to body
        use_effect_with_deps(
            move |_| {
                let body = document().body().unwrap();
                body.add_event_listener_with_callback("click", (*close).as_ref().unchecked_ref())
                    .unwrap();

                // Clean up the event listener when the component is unmounted
                let close_clone = close.clone();
                move || {
                    body.remove_event_listener_with_callback(
                        "click",
                        (*close_clone).as_ref().unchecked_ref(),
                    )
                    .unwrap();
                }
            },
            (),
        );
    }

    html! {
        <main>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <a
                    class={classes!("btn", "btn-secondary", "dropdown-toggle")}
                    href="#" role="button"
                    data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                    aria-expanded="false"
                    {onclick}
                >
                 {"Dropdown link"}
                </a>

                <ul class={classes!("dropdown-menu", (*is_open).clone().then(|| Some("show")))}>
                 <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{"Action"}</a></li>
                 <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{"Another action"}</a></li>
                 <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{"Something else here"}</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </main>
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked great but I had to edit it a little. change `use_effect_with_deps` to `use_effect` and remove the second argument `()`